# Convert web application project to maven project and convert corresponding .classpath file to pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, classpath, pom.xml

Is it possible to convert project .classpath file to pom.xml after converting a simple web application project to maven project? Because if my project uses many jars and I want to convert it to maven then I will do configure->convert to maven but then it is not possible to add all the jars dependencies in pom.xml manually. So is there any tool to convert this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First there is no tool to do such things. The problem is usually that you have a larger number of dependencies which you don't need to put into the **pom.xml** file, cause Maven handles [transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) which means you only need to add only direct dependencies. The best thing is to look at the current projects jar files and try to find them in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and cut&paste the information form the search output into your pom. And of course test the build via Maven on command line.